TOC , hyperref and unnumbered sections
I need to add an unnumbered section (with a special formatting). The problem that I met is that the hyperlink in the TOC is not the good one. Is there a modern easy fix of this?
Here is my M(not)WE.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Before}

\newpage Unuseful \newpage

\bgroup
    \titleformat{\section}[block]{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
    \section*{My annex}%
    \label{annex-label}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{My annex}%
\egroup

\section{After}

\end{document}


Have you read section “11.1.33 titlesec” in the hyperref documentation → https://markov.htwsaar.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.html#x1-9800011.1.33 (note: this second link may become invalid in future).

Yes. Just now! :-) What is strange to me is that the page indicated is the good one.

Isn't there a \phantomsection missing for the hyperlink to refer to. Added before the label

@daleif Thanks. This is the easy fix! I have added the solution using \phantomsection.

BTW: AFAIK hyperref tries to redefine some titlesec macros, but only, if it is loaded after titlesec. So you should IMHO change the order.

@cabohah This doesn't work.

@projetmbc This is independent from your problem.

There are alternatives for article with build-in user interfaces for configuration of sections and better support for not numbered sections with ToC entries, e.g., the KOMA-Script class article:
\documentclass[headings=standardclasses]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Before}

\newpage Unuseful \newpage

\bgroup
    \setkomafont{section}{\Huge}%
    \let\raggedsection\centering
    \addsec{My annex}%
    \label{annex-label}
\egroup

\section{After}

\end{document}

Here also the link anchor to "My annex" in the bookmarks and the table of contents is suitable. Nevertheless, I would not recommend to make such massive changes of only one section heading, but use, e.g., \addpart:
\documentclass[headings=standardclasses]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\raggedpart\centering
%\setkomafont{part}{\Huge}% optional

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Before}

\newpage Unuseful \newpage

\addpart{My annex}%
\label{annex-label}

\section{After}

\end{document}

Another alternative could be memoir. See the documentation for more information.

Thanks for this proposition. This works also.

Thanks to the advice of @daelif, here is an easy fix.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Before}

\newpage Unuseful \newpage

\bgroup
    \titleformat{\section}[block]{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
    \phantomsection\section*{My annex}%
    \label{annex-label}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{My annex}%
\egroup

Unuseful

\newpage Unuseful \newpage

\section{After}

\end{document}


such a phantomsection in vertical mode can end up on the wrong (previous) page.

Place it after section*

@daleif This links to the text just after the unnumbered section.

@UlrikeFischer In my case, there will have always a \newpage just before the unnumbered section.
